# Locking down external drive reads in a permanent fashion on Linux?

Tags: linux, security

Is there any way to alter the way a Linux distribution handles external drives to only allow read-only unless additional credentials are provided, or at least permanently disable it?

Basically need it such that if someone plugs a drive into a system with sensitive data, they cannot copy anything off, even with admin rights.

I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 specifically, and ideally I'd need to do a bunch of setup on the system before disabling this functionality, so I'm not sure if say, modifying and recompiling the OS is possible. Ideally this needs to be a fairly difficult thing to overcome on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out how your external drives are mounted.

On Ubuntu 16.04, I guess udev is used, in which case you can create a rule, as noted on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/196764/auto-mount-usb-drives-read-only).

About the fact that you don't want users to be able to copy anything, even with "admin rights", you could just set up sudo rules in order not to allow them to remount the drive. Of course, you could also change your kernel, which would be more effective but also harder to do and maintain.

Comment: I mean being admin and being sudo is equivalent in Linux... I want a person who does have sudo permissions to not be able to do this. For the udev solution, is it possible to make that rule permanent? IE someone can create it but someone can delete it too, and this needs to be a permanent measure.

Comment: As I said, you can set up your sudo rules to restrict sudo operations for some users/groups. That's why being admin is not necessarily only having sudo, you could use sudo yet not be able to get root access. Digital Ocean provides some nice [examples](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos#how-to-set-up-custom-rules) on how to do that.